# Fade in and fade out GUI.Box

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to fade in and fade out a GUI.Box?  I tried searching but can only find how to fade text.

```
void OnGUI()
{

    GUI.Box(new Rect(20, 20, 300, 100), "Find pH of paper");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using OnGUI function is not recommended since the new GUI system of Unity.

Anyway, the GUI class provides a static attribute called [GUI.backgroundColor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI-backgroundColor.html)

Simply set the value of the color over time. However, I don't know if the alpha will be taken into account with the OnGUI function.

Here is an example to do so :

```
private void Update()
{
     GUI.backgroundColor = Color.Lerp(Color.white, Color.clear, Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, 1));
}
```

You can also use [Coroutines](https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/coroutines) if you want to start the fade when the user does an action for example.

```
private IEnumerator FadeIn( float duration = 1 )
{
     for( float t = 0 ; t < duration ; t += Time.deltaTime )
     {
          GUI.backgroundColor = Color.Lerp(Color.clear, Color.white, t / duration);
          yield return null ;
     }
}
```

---

Using the UGUI system is easier, cleaner and faster. Changing the color of a sprite, or the [alpha value of a Canvas Group](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CanvasGroup-alpha.html) will be a piece of cake !